# Chrome extension: function must be called during a user gesture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

In a Chrome Extension I want to ask the user for full access to pages through a browser_action's popup's link (aka a toolbar popup with a link). When the user clicks the link, I get this error:

`runtime.lastError while running permissions.request: This function must be called during a user gesture`

Yet the user actually clicked the link and the 'user gesture'. Any ideas of how to debug what is considered a user gesture?

On the button click, I request full access via chrome's [`chrome.permissions.request`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) api:

```
$('#button-requestpermissions').click(function(){
  requestAmbientPermission(function(granted) {
    if (granted) {
      // code never reached as granted === false
    } 
  });
});

function requestAmbientPermission(callback){
    // Permissions must be requested from inside a user gesture, like a button's click handler.
    chrome.permissions.request({
      permissions: ['activeTab'],
      origins: ['<all_urls>']
    }, callback);
}
```

The manifest has optional permissions set like so:

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://www.meethue.com/",
    "https://colorlovers.herokuapp.com/"
  ],
  "optional_permissions": [ 
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

Comment: Likely the request permission code needs to execute from the background page not the content script

Comment: Zig, I did try to bruteforse the solution - executing the permissions.request from the background page produces same error.

Comment: Please note: `activeTab` permission generates no warning. It was [made for that specific purpose](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab). Therefore, there is really no need to make that optional.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer? You can only request a new permission from a user action, for example, a button clicked:

```
document.querySelector('#my-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Permissions must be requested from inside a user gesture, like a button's
    // click handler.
    chrome.permissions.request({
      permissions: ['tabs'],
      origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
    }, function(granted) {
      // The callback argument will be true if the user granted the permissions.
      if (granted) {
        doSomething();
      } else {
        doSomethingElse();
      }
    });
});
```

A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions#property-Permissions-origins)

Answer (score 0):

Got the error when requesting permission even when the code was inside a user gesture call back.

```
runtime.lastError while running permissions.request: This function must be called during a user gesture
```

It happens only when I put a debugger before executing the API. When I removed the debugger and let the API execute without any intermediate blockers it was rectified. For any debugging, I have used console.log since then.

I guess the reason for this is when the debugger stops the code execution and we do some user interaction on the browser in debugging mode, and we start the execution again, chrome decides this code block is not associated with to last interaction so not allowed.